# Add more memory to Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a Dell 2900 Server with 16 GB of memory running SQL Server 2005.

All 3 of the databases I have configured on the Server all have the maximum memory allocated to each Database. The primary database runs my production environment of our BAAN application, the other two databases run a development environment.

Besides reducing the amount of memory used in the other 2 Databases, is there a command I can issue to show the memory used by each database?

Comment: Are you maybe confusing memory with storage?

Comment: or databases with instances?

Answer (score 3):

Try the query below:

```
SELECT (count(*)*0.0078125) AS 'Pages in Buffer pool'
    ,CASE database_id
        WHEN 32767 THEN 'ResourceDb'
        ELSE db_name(database_id)
        END AS Database_name
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY db_name(database_id) ,database_id
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

This will show you the amount of space each DB has occupied in the buffer pool. Note that there are [other factors](http://stanleyjohns.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/to-find-the-percentage-of-an-object-in-memory/) in SQL that also use up the memory apart from the buffer pool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to limit or show the amount of memory used by individual DBs in SQL Server.  If you are having memory issues, I think what you're probably better off doing is to install a second instance of SQL on that server, use it to host the dev environments and limit it to a certain amount of memory (like a GB or two) in the server options.